# Взаимодействие между компонентами

Tags: angular2

У меня есть 2 компонента регистрации и логина. Нужно, чтобы после успешной регистрации перекидывало на страницу логина и показывало определенное сообщение в течении 10 секунд.

Как компонент должен "понять", что регистрация была успешно и показать сообщение?

Comment: ну наверное сервер должен возвращать 200/201 ? :)

Comment: он возвращает, но я перехожу на другую страницу

Comment: в каком смысле? :)

Comment: чтобы после успешной регистрации перекидывало на страницу логина и показывало определенное сообщение в течении 10 секунд.

Comment: т.е в компоненте register я регистрирую нового пользователя и перехожу на компоненту login

Comment: и как мне в темплэйте компонента login отобразить сообщение которое должно появляться после регистрации

Comment: ну, создайте руками какой-то див и аппендите его в `document.body` и пропишите для него стили, и удаляйте из дома через 10 секунд `setTimeout(() => someDiv.remove(), 10000)`

Comment: спасибо, так и сделал

Comment: Какой ужасный совет...

Comment: а как ты посоветуешь?